# How to request GeoServer elevation data from GeoServer to PNG file with the minimum loss of precision

Tags: wms, elevation, png

I'm requesting alt data on GeoServer from a layer group as a PNG file. The colormap of the style associated with the layer is the following :

```
<ColorMap>
     <ColorMapEntry color="#000000" quantity="-27" label="values" />// altitude min
     <ColorMapEntry color="#FF0000" quantity="4787"/> // altitude max
</ColorMap>
```

Which means the altitude is interpolated from black for min alt -27m to red for max alt 4787m.

As it is encoded in a 8bit png file, I only have 256 value between red and black and as consequences for my PNG, I only have a vertical precision of (4787 - (-27))/256 = 18 meters which is not quite good for what I want.
Are there other technique to have a better vertical precision in my PNG file to tackle this problem and take full advantage of the 256 x 256 x 256 = 16 777 216 values of the RGB channel which could theorically give me a much better vertical precision.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: All of the code of my product relies on WMS so change it would be too difficult. Is there any plugin in Geoserver to encode alt in PNG file such as in this link https://observablehq.com/@sw1227/decoding-png-elevation-tile.
It's quite deceptive to use very accurate Geotiff in input of my GeoServer and get inaccurate data from it.

Comment: @bellotnicolas did you manage to retrieve more more detailled information from a WMS (or Geoserver) request?